# adding to an href

Tags: jquery

I want to add to an href when a link becomes "active" My code selects a specific class, adds a class and then, if it is a specific file, needs this additional input ("?lightbox[width]=350&lightbox[height]=170") added to the href. My code is as follows:

```
 $('.active').removeClass("lightbox").addClass("lightbox");

$('.active  [href$='.swf'],[href$='.mov'],[href$='.flv'],[href$='.wmv']').attr("href", function(i, href) 
{return href + '?lightbox[width]=350&lightbox[height]=170';
```

Doesn't want to add to the href. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm fascinated by the first line: *why* are you selecting an element and then removing, then replacing, the class `'lightbox'`?

Comment: @David, ahahahahh good catch. That's hilarious. Maybe the first `lightbox` class is haunted by evil spirits?

Comment: Thanks. The reason I used .removeClass("lightbox").addClass("lightbox"); is that another javascript ( image gallery) is manipulating the code and I was trying to make sure that the lightbox class was really removed before apllying it again if the user clicked on the same image a second time. I had seen this code on this site before so I used it as well as for evil spirits, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".active")
  .filter("[href$='.swf'],[href$='.mov'],[href$='.flv'],[href$='.wmv']")
  .attr("href", function(i, href) {
    return href + '?lightbox[width]=350&lightbox[height]=170';
  });
```

I changed the outer quotes to double because you are already using single quotes inside the selector. If you want to have quotes inside a string, than you have to make sure that they are not of the same type as the ones that encapsulate the string:

```
"This 'string' is OK"
'This "one" also'
```

I also changed the code to first select all ".active" elements, and then filter out the one's which href attribute doesn't end with the desired strings (.swf, .mov, .flv or .wmv). The way your code was working was that the ".active" selector applied only to the first [href] selector.

***Another thing...***

Since the dot character is a meta-character in a selector, you may try to escape it.

Instead of this:

```
.filter("[href$='.swf'],[href$='.mov'],[href$='.flv'],[href$='.wmv']")
```

try this:

```
.filter("[href$='\\.swf'],[href$='\\.mov'],[href$='\\.flv'],[href$='\\.wmv']")
```

***Update!***

I did some testing and the `\\` escape does not work but the `\` escape does. Also, in my browser - Chrome on Win7 - it works even without escaping.

Comment: Given the nature of the question, I'm assuming that @Mike's fairly new to jQuery/JavaScript, so you might want to explain *why* this works, and his approach didn't.

Comment: @David Good idea :) I normally explain further only if the OP doesn't get it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer. The code isn't working but I will keep trying! learning Jquery a step at a time…..

Comment: @Mike I updated my answer. Try escaping the dot characters with \\

Comment: Why not just remove the `.`? Since you're using the ends-with selector it doesn't necessarily add anything to the selector that the file-type itself wouldn't do by itself.

Comment: @David But then that would also select elements with href attributes like "www.foo.com/movies/wmv" (in this case "wmv" is a directory, and we want to select only href's that point to ".wmv" files, and **not** any href that ends with "wmv").

Comment: @Mike What did the trick? Escaping the dots with \\ or removing them?

Comment: Good point about the selecting the element issue if it is wmv, etc. Removing  the dots

Comment: @Mike Have you tried escaping them with \\? I am curious to know if that works in this case...

Comment: Just updating my Mac to 10.6.5 now so I will try after restart and let you know.

Comment: @Mike I did a small demo and it works in my browser **with the dots and without escaping them**. Here is the demo: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/jquery-href-ends-with.html

Comment: Thanks for making the demo. i will see what I am doing wrong on my end and let you know.